# SSL certificate issue unable to get local issuer certificate in cpanel

Tags: php, curl

```
$fields['username'] = "Pass@1234";
$fields['password'] = "harsha";
// set postfields using what we extracted from the form
$POSTFIELDS = http_build_query($fields); 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://website.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/abc.crt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://website.com");
$page = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
echo $page;
```

I have to save .pem file path in PHP ini but still, it shows "SSL certificate problem unable to get local issuer certificate error"

Comment: actually i have login to facebook with the above code successfully. but the site which i want to login shows the above error . and if i comment the line curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/abc.crt"); it redirects to the url but not get logged in

Comment: Note that you can [edit] your question to improve it.